# nativescript rborn nativescript-i18n change language in app

Tags: angular, nativescript

I'm using rborn/nativescript-i18n to internationalize my Nativescript App + Angular4.

All is working fine !

I would like to let the user force the language in the app by selecting a language in a select list.

But I don't find how to do that in that lib... may i use another lib ?

Ty.

Answer (score 0):

@ngx-translate allows the app to change the language dynamically.